# The program is an exercise that should be a scrabble game, it works fine but when the words are the same but the case differs player 2 always wins

Tags: c, cs50

This is the code in its current state.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    printf("%i\n%i\n", score1, score2);
    if(score1 == score2)
    {
        printf("It's a tie\n");
    }
    else if(score1 < score2)
    {
        printf("Player 2 wins!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Player 1 wins!!!\n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    int score;
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(word[i]))
        {
            if(word[i]>='A' && word[i] <='Z')
            {
            int y = (int)(word[i] - 65);
            score = score + POINTS[y];
            }
        }
        if(islower(word[i]))
        {
            if(word[i]>='a' && word[i] <='z')
            {
            int z = (int)(word[i] - 97);
            score = score + POINTS[z];
            }
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

It kinda works but the error is when the words are the same but the lettercase is different.
[Also the order does not matter, player 2 always gets the double of the points, cant really understand why it is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSotB.png)

Comment: `int score;` ==> `int score = 0;` The compiler should have warned you about an *uninitialised variable*.

Comment: thanks man, never would've thought that this is what caused it

Answer (score 0):

Save time.  Enable all warnings which rapidly point to the issue.  Faster than posting on SO.

Example warning

```
warning: 'score' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

Fix:

```
int compute_score(string word) {
  // int score;
  int score = 0;
  ...
```